# Programmatically add to Window.Resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to add a ResourceDictionary at the Window level instead of the Application level?

I see many examples for something like this:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

However, nothing like what I would expect there to be, such as:

```
Window.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do:

```
Window.Resources
```

However, you **can** do:

```
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

[Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources.aspx) is a property of FrameworkElement, and is shared by Application and Window (and most other user interface classes in WPF).  However, it is an instance property, not a static property, so you need to work with the resources *of a specific instance*.  When you typed "Window.Resources" you were trying to add to the "window" type, not to a specific Window.

This works in your Application line since [Application.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current.aspx) returns the current instance of an Application, so you're working with the correct, specific instance (not the type).

Comment: If I do this, are the references to the resources now DynamicResource instead of StaticResource?  (I took the styles off the window pages themselves and put them into a Dictionary)

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed: Yes, basically.  THere's no way for them to be resolvable at compile time, so they have to be treated dynamically...